# How to change the slider length of the scrollbar according to the size of canvas object?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am drawing canvas line objects by specifying the coordinates of them via scale and spinbox widgets.

Below is the function that runs when i use scale or spinbox.

```
    def change_borehole_depth(self, var):
        for k, v in self.objects.items():
            self.delete(v)
        self.objects = {}
        if var.get():
            self.depth_of_borehole(meter=var.get(), size=75)
```

Normally, if I call `self.depth_of_borehole` function with precise parameters in the `__init__` method, the slider of the scrollbar automatically reshapes according to the coordinates of the line objects. However when I use the `scale` and `spinbox` to change the minimum and maximum y coordinates, the shape of the slider doesn't change. But it changes after I click to the slider.

The other functions work well, so I am just sharing the `self.change_borehole_depth` function because this is the function that specifies the size of the lines when I us the `scale` and `spinbox`. There's no problem in creating the lines according the `var`. The problem is just that, the slider of the scrollbar is not resizing/reshaping automatically. In order to solve this problem I tried to use `update` method first. But it didn't work. Then I used `update_idletasks` method but it neither worked. I also used `set` but it worked neither.

I am sharing some screenshots that I hope they can be helpful to make the problem being understood well.

Before clicking the slider of the scrollbar:

[image]

After clicking the slider of the scrollbar:
[image]

When the coordinates of the line object has been changed, the length of the slider isn't changing.
[image]

So, what should I do to solve this problem. If necesarry I can share the rest of the codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I changed the `change_borehole_depth` function to below.

```
    def change_borehole_depth(self, var):
        for k, v in self.objects.items():
            self.delete(v)
        self.objects = {}
        if var.get():
            self.depth_of_borehole(meter=var.get(), size=75)
            self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox("all"))
            self.update()
```